# xdg-open : no method available even after installing xdg-utils

Tags: express, gruntjs, yeoman, xdgutils

I am using generator-angular-fullstack.
On my local machine its working fine, I run

```
 grunt serve
```

it starts server but in VPS it's failing

```
Warning: Command failed: xdg-open: no method available for opening 'http://localhost:9000'
```

and I have already installed xdg-utils

```
 $ sudo apt-get install xdg-utils
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 xdg-utils is already the newest version.
```

Can any one explain me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you have `xdg-open` installed? Try to run it from console. Second suggest: try to change hostname to "0.0.0.0". And show us Gruntfile please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using graphical environment? If you are using "raspberry" and you are connecting via ssh and you have no "grunt" configured to use PhantomJS, "Grunt" can not perform the task. You have to force him to continue to "serve --force grunt" or set the "Gruntfile.js"

Comment: Since the question was so long ago I can't test the answer. Yes, I was not using GUI interface. Maybe that's the reason.

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried configuring the `xdg-open` handlers?

Also, have you ensured you have a browser installed on your server? Installing a new browser with `apt-get install <browser>` should automatically make `xdg-open` aware of it. However, your setup may not have done this depending on the order that your browser/xdg-utils were installed.

To make things sane again requires running `xdg-settings`.

To set an `http://` handler to your preferred browser (which on a headless server is likely to be `w3m`, `lynx` or `elinks`), do the following:

`xdg-settings set default-web-browser w3m.desktop`

To verify,  you can run `xdg-open https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683221` and you should see your answer in w3m.

If you don't have `w3m` available, install it with `sudo apt-get install w3m`

You may wish to see other available handlers by running `xdg-settings --list`, which on my system, outputs the following:

```
Known properties:
  default-url-scheme-handler    Default handler for URL scheme
  default-web-browser           Default web browser
```

**EDIT:**
It turns out that some old systems (ubuntu 10.04) don't have `xdg-settings`, and that the `update-alternatives` command should automatically configure `xdg-open`.  Like so:

```
    sudo update-alternatives --config www-browser
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not an expert with `xdg-open` but I will give this a try. It looks like there is a problem with your package database. Also, showing the gruntfile would make things easier.

Here are the steps to follow:

1. Identify all `xdg-open`'s.

   `$ type -a xdg-open`

   `xdg-open is /usr/bin/xdg-open`
2. Find out which packages they're a part of.

   `$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/xdg-open`

   `xdg-utils: /usr/bin/xdg-open`
3. You'll want to either repeat the above `dpkg -S ..` for each match returned by `type -a` **or** use this `dpkg -S ..` search instead. I would do each, one at a time.

   `$ dpkg -S xdg-open`

   `xdg-utils: /usr/bin/xdg-open`

   `xdg-utils: /usr/share/man/man1/xdg-open.1.gz`
4. Reinstalling xdg-utils. If you'd like to refresh this package's installation do this:

   `$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall xdg-utils`

I hope this helps!

Comment: the correct way to reinstall a package is `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xdg-utils`

Comment: @sdotdi See step 4 of my answer

Comment: Copy and paste it to the terminal until you see what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

I did `sudo apt install wslu` like mentioned [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8892#issuecomment-1428022076) and it seems to fix it.