# Snowflake ODBC xdg-open Missing X server or $DISPLAY

Tags: r, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, odbc, rodbc

I've asked this question from Posit Community but did not get any answer so far:

https://forum.posit.co/t/snowflake-odbc-connection-xdg-open-missing-x-server-or-display/184074

I'm following up [this page](https://solutions.posit.co/connections/db/databases/snowflake/?_gl=1*17rxt29*_ga*MjA4ODQ1MDQ5MC4xNzExMjk2Nzcx*_ga_2C0WZ1JHG0*MTcxMTc1NTY1NS41LjEuMTcxMTc1NTY3Ni4wLjAuMA..) and [this page](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/odbc/odbc-parameters) to ODBC connect to Snowflake with R/Rstudio. I explained my environment and the code I ran in the above link. Error I'm getting is, I think, related to R console not being able to open a browser page for Snowflake authentication.

Thanks

Comment: I've never seen setting the display to `"localhost:10.0 && /usr/bin/google-chrome"`, in my experience that variable should always be something like `localhost:10.0`. The `DISPLAY` variable is not "how to display", it is "on which device to display graphical windows/things", and should almost always be a hostname, colon, and a number (that is translated into a network port). You cannot just make this up, there must be some X-windows (or wayland) display that is connected to that hostname/number.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Already tested with "localhost:10.0" and got the same error. BTW I did not "just make this up", it's mentioned in a few places like this page (https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/8148#issuecomment-1204965369)

Comment: You took that puppeteer discussion too literally. The `DISPLAY=localhost:10.0` is one thing, and then the shell in that example evaluated `&& /usr/bin/google-chrome`. That latter portion is not part of the envvar. Second, the point about "not making it up" is that `localhost:10.0` must point to an already established connection, it is not magic. You need to know that there is something actively listening on `localhost` on port `6010` (because of `10:0`) and doing something deliberate with communications on that port. If you don't know that, then it is likely not the way to go.

Comment: FYI, in shell scripts, I think `export DISPLAY=$HOST_IP:10.0 && /usr/bin/google-chrome` would be much more clearly done as `DISPLAY=$HOST_IP:10.0 /usr/bin/google-chrome` assuming only one command needs that envvar, or as `export DISPLAY=$HOST_IP:10.0 ; /usr/bin/google-chrome` since `export DISPLAY=..` will never fail (though it might not point to a recognized port).

Comment: In https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-fed-auth-use#label-browser-based-sso, it says that `authenticator=externalbrowser` must be set in the `odbc.ini`, I don't see that in your file listings. While I may have assumed as well that including it in `dbConnect` should have worked, have you tried adding it to `/etc/odbc.ini`?

Comment: Also, assuming your python/jupyter code successfully connects, is it intentional that you are using different values for `database=` and `warehouse=`, and no `schema=`?

Comment: Looking at the log code (I'm slowing getting through it, sorry for the stream of thoughts), it looks like the real problem (discarding `DISPLAY=` above) is that `xdg-open` does not work for you, and I think _that_ is the key. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/24683221/3358272 to see if you can fix it. You should be able to do a quick test (on your shell prompt, not in R) by trying `xdg-open https://google.com` (or some `https://` URI). When you can get that to work, then retry your database connection efforts.

Comment: Thanks much for sharing your thoughts, this is quite helpful. Starting from bottom to top, running `xdg-open https://google.com` on prompt gives below errors


grep: /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/WSLInterop: No such file or directory
[error] You should use Bash 5 and higher; exiting.
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 862: links2: command not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 862: elinks: command not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 862: links: command not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 862: lynx: command not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 862: w3m: command not found

Comment: I was able to yum install Lynx, now when I run `xdg-open https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78246396` a page opens inside shell and I can see this page. But I still get the same error when running the code in RStudio.

Comment: I would not be surprised if the external-browser authentication required for snowflake would not work as well in a text-based browser. I don't _know_ that it won't, but there may be modern-browser requirements (javascript? idk) that are not readily available in lynx. However, the use of this mechanism from within RStudio is going to need a graphical web browser, not text-based like lynx. Keep looking for how to configure your `xdg-settings` to use firefox, chrome, or whatever graphical browser you have installed.

Comment: Done a few more steps, but still got Missing X server or $DISPLAY error.

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-www-browser x-www-browser /usr/bin/google-chrome 500
sudo update-alternatives --set x-www-browser /usr/bin/google-chrome
sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser

$ echo $BROWSER
/usr/bin/google-chrome
$ xdg-settings get default-web-browser
google-chrome.desktop
$ xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/http
google-chrome.desktop
$ xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/https
google-chrome.desktop
$ xdg-mime query default text/html
google-chrome.desktop

Comment: Comments are not well-suited for long data or code chunks, especially when newlines are there. I suggest you edit your question and add these new steps there. (Frankly, the question should have more self-contained content, it's generally frowned upon to have all information in an off-site link.)